# Beginner help-Hybrid mobile app development

Tags: mobile, architecture, frameworks, hybrid, mobile-development

I have developed applications in J2ME and for Android. I am planning to learn and develop hybrid applications using HTML5/JavaScript/jQuery or AngularJS. Is there a place where I can get information on the different frameworks and how hybrid architecture should be used?

Any books for beginners in hybrid development?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/). Its a cloud based IDE for cross-platform development. Their documentation has all the tutorials and sample for you to learn HTML5/Javascript/AngularJS.

I started as a beginner and now learnt a lot through developing on Monaca. You can also check out Monaca's product [OnsenUI](http://onsenui.io/) which is a smooth interface for cross-platform and PhoneGap apps.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check this out. What do think about Xamarin? I would like to develop with C#.

Answer (score 0):

f you are new to Hybrid application, then use the INTEL XDK for developing your application. Download the sdk and create a new project and you can edit the index.html page in www folder. After complete the coding ,you can build your android/ios/windows/chrome/web application by selecting the build tab and provide certificates and build with just click start building. Hope this help you